# Rails: Submit Local Variables from view to another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

My View:

```
<div class="field">

  <%= label :isbn_exist, 'ISBN' %>
  <%= text_field :isbn_exist,'ISBN' %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Add new book', new_book_path(:isbn_exist => @isbn_exist), :class => "btn btn-warning"%>
```

This ":isbn_exist" variable is not sent to the controller. why? If i put a number instead of `@isbn_exist` this value is sent. I think the `text_field` is not saving the value on the `:isbn_exist` variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `text_field` and a link. What you really want is a `form` (including this `text_field`) and a `submit` button.

Things like this are covered in every rails tutorial you can find.